# SyntaxError: (node:3680) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am just trying to setup a crud on node.js with mongodb.
I am new and kind of following a tutorial.

getting the below error that seems unsolvable

```
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1053:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

here is my index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
 

var app = express();
var port = 3000;
 
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{res.send('hi')});
app.listen(port,()=> {console.log('server live @ '+port)});
```

here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "nodementor",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "author": "krishna",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.0"
  }
}
```

So far tried adding `"type": "module",` in `package.json` which again gives out another error

```
(node:3680) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
file:///D:/MEAN/nodementor/index.js:1

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:122:18)
    at async link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:42:21)
```

Comment: Code works fine for me, how are you trying to run the server? Also, please link us to the tutorial.

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.google.com/search?q=SyntaxError:+Invalid+or+unexpected+token+at+wrapSafe+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: @ChrisG  here is the one that i am trying to follow https://www.jenniferbland.com/saving-data-to-mongodb-database-from-node-js-application-tutorial/

Comment: Did you check out mplungjan's link? This might be an encoding issue, or a stray character. The code is fine, so make sure your JS file is UTF-8, and make sure there are no special characters in it like unicode spaces.

Comment: @mplungjan most answers suggest incorrect encoding i have verified mine is UTF-8

Comment: Seems fixed, I did a clean install of node.js and restarted my pc.

Comment: Feel free to delete or post answer